# Callback argument in symfony service container

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony, inversion-of-control

I'm working with Symfony's injection container and the Serializer component to provide a service with the default serialization configuration each time. Specifically working with the ObjectNormalizer:

```
 <service
     id="my_bundle.entity_serializer_normalizer"
     class="Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer"
 >
     <argument type="service" id="my_bundle.entity_serializer_normalizer_metadata_factory" />
     <argument>null</argument>
     <argument>null</argument>
     <argument type="service" id="my_bundle.entity_serializer_normalizer_reflection_extractor" />

     <call method="setIgnoredAttributes">
         <argument type="collection">
             <argument>__initializer__</argument>
             <argument>__cloner__</argument>
             <argument>__isInitialized__</argument>
         </argument>
     </call>

 </service>
```

However there is a method on this service I also need to call to set the circular reference handler. In regular PHP this would look like this:

```
$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
    return $object->getId();
});
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to add this to a `<call>` in the container.

I've looked into using the new expression engine feature to try this but it doesn't seem to match up with a callback. I've also pondered if adding a stand-alone function somewhere and registering it would make this work. Right now I'm hacking the method call into the class my serializer is injected into.

I've also attempted manually adding it via a secondary PHP definition:

```
$container->set(
    'tactic_monolith.entity_serializer_normalizer_circular_reference_handler',
    function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    }
);
```

However it seems to be silently ignored. When doing a setParameter I receive an error (callables cannot be parameters). I have also attempted to register this as a snythetic service.

Comment: You need to use the **setCircularReferenceHandler** to get rid of the CircularReferenceError only ? And you did not tag your normalizer with **serializer.normalizer**, so how does your serializer know he has to use this ObjectSerializer instead of the default one ?

Comment: Correct, `setCircularReferenceHandler` is only to prevent crawling my circular references. I create a serializer service definition with this normalizer and `$this->get('my.custom_serializer')`.

Comment: Symfony [Serializer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) provide serialization in two steps : **normalization** (with Normalizers like CustomObjectNormalizer or ObjectNormalizer for example) and **encoding** (with Encoders). In your case you want to customize the normalization process, you don't need to customize the entire serializer.  Create a custom object normalizer, tag it with **serializer.normalizer** and simply use your serializer `$this->get('serializer')` . The serializer will use your custom normalizer automatically.

Comment: That is interesting, do you mean something like this where they implement a `UserNormalizer` http://thomas.jarrand.fr/blog/serialization/ ? I don't know if i will use the tag as I'm not sure I want this to change the behavior of my `serializer` service everywhere.

Comment: Yes something like this. In the article you show me, look for this "Your domain logic lies into the normalizer". That's what I am talking about. You can create normalizers as much as you want and declare them with your default serializer. And what is the goal eventually ? use a the correct normalizer when needed. It is up to you if you want to use this method provided by symfony framework or not

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's no way to do this without using a factory.

```
class CircularHandlerFactory
{
    public static function getId(){
        return (function ($object) {
            return $object->getId();
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
<service
    id="some_bundle.circular_reference_handler"
    class="callback"
>
    <factory class="SomeBundle\CircularHandlerFactory" method="getId" />
</service>
```

Finally adding the call to the normalizer:

```
<call method="setCircularReferenceHandler">
    <argument type="service" id="some_bundle.circular_reference_handler"/>
</call>
```

In hindsight, perhaps this would have been inappropriate usage of the feature. However, this may also be something worthwhile for a feature request of the expression engine.